# Git branches for working on dev while merging some changes into the master

Tags: git

Previously, using SVN, I would have a branch that was my development branch, which matched the code on the development site. Once in a while, I would make a change in the development branch and then merge just the change into the trunk so I could put it on production. I'm wondering how I might accomplish something similar with git.

Basically, I want to be able merge 1 or a few commits from the branch into the master without merging the entire branch.

Or should I be working with git differently? (I need to release the changes right away so I can't way till all the changes are done.) Should I be working with multiple branches? Can I merge 1 branch into multiple other branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost answered your question: yes, you can merge one branch into multiple other branches.

So, what you want to do is create a branch just for this feature/bugfix (the common name is "topic"), starting from a common ancestor of all branches you'll want to merge it into. Do your work, commit it, then merge it into all of those.

```
# say version 1.2.3 is a common ancestor, and it's tagged
git checkout -b bugfix v1.2.3

# do some stuff
git add ...
git commit

git checkout master
git merge bugfix

git checkout dev
git merge bugfix
...
```

The key part here is to **make sure to start your branch at a common ancestor**. If you don't, you'll end up merging pieces of other things in as well.

If for some reason it's difficult to find a good common ancestor, you can fall back to [cherry-picking](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html). This essentially copies a commit from one place to another. It's best to avoid it when you can, though, since it does mean you end up with two copies of a commit in the history.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to make "topic branches" in git, where I implement a feature in its own branch. Then I can choose if I merge it into development or production or both. This allows feature development to continue, while bug fixes can still be applied to production in a reasonable amount of time.

Its similar in concept to the model explained here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/