# Git - checkout new commits from another branch

Tags: git, dotfiles

I use git to manage my dotfiles, I use both linux and mac osx so I create separate branches for these two and another master for the common settings.

When I edit something which is common and I want to save the changes to another branch. This is how I work at the moment:

```
git checkout master
git commit ...
git checkout arch
git checkout master <file1>
git checkout master <file2>
```

This is a lot of work. Can I checkout a commit instead of file, or is there any even shorter way than this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of cherry-picking ([see its disadvantage here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)), I would rather merge `master` in the other branches.

See for instance "[Git branches for working on `dev` while merging some changes into the `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542708/git-branches-for-working-on-dev-while-merging-some-changes-into-the-master)".
That way, you know what was already integrated into your branches from `master`.

Comment: in arch branch for example, I have another arch folder which doesn't exist in master. So If I merge master in arch, this will delete that folder which is not what I want. But does I misunderstand something ?

Comment: @Vdt it shouldn't delete the directory, unless you had that directory in `master` first and deleted there. If you introduced that directory in your `arch` branch (so *after* branching from `master`), a merge from `master` won't touch it.

Comment: yes, it's exactly the situation I've been on. How can I avoid deleting these folders ?

Comment: @Vdt Then you might do the merge, then restore the directory. That merge will record a merge link between master and arch, and any subsequent merge won't touch the directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also love the idea of making thing work properly instead of dirty tips and tricks to make it work but not right ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `git cherry-pick <changeset hash>`. E.g. `git cherry-pick 1a15f41e2`. This will apply the commit to current branch. If the commit exists only in remote repo you will have to do git fetch before cherry picking. Documentation: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html

Comment: You can also investigate the `-n` option of `git cherry-pick` if you want to apply multiple commits as a single one.